# how can i use the foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables

```
TabelAnunturi

idAnunta    |DataInterval   |Denumire   |Moderatori |Detalii
2           |text           |text       |text       |text
2           |text           |text       |text       |text
3           |text           |text       |text       |text
3           |text           |text       |text       |text
```

and

```
Anunturi

idAnunt     |Data   |Subiect    |Anunt  |AnuntContinuare
1           |text   |text       |text   |text
2           |text   |text       |text   |text
3           |text   |text       |text   |text
4           |text   |text       |text   |text
```

I have a query that gets the data from both tables with `JOIN ON`

```
$constructtabelanunturi = "SELECT t.DataInterval, t.Denumire, t.Moderatori, t.Detalii FROM TabelAnunturi t JOIN Anunturi a ON (t.idAnunta = a.idAnunt)";
```

and a script that checks if there are results from the query and if so, displays the results...

```
echo "
<div class='noutati'>
    <table class='dataanunturi'>
        <tr>
            <td class='data'>{$runrows ['Data']}</td>
            <td class='subiect'>Subiect:</td>
            <td>{$runrows ['Subiect']}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {$runrows ['Anunt']} ";

    while($runrowstabelanunturi = mysql_fetch_assoc($runtabelanunturi))
    {
        $DataInterval = $runrowstabelanunturi ['DataInterval'];
        $Denumire = $runrowstabelanunturi ['Denumire'];
        $Moderatori = $runrowstabelanunturi ['Moderatori'];
        $Detalii = $runrowstabelanunturi ['Detalii'];
        echo"
        <br>
        <br>
        <table class=\"anunturi\">
            <tr>
                <th class=\"dataanunturi\">Dată / Interval orar</th>
                <th class=\"denumire\">Denumire</th>
                <th class=\"moderatori\">Moderatori</th>
                <th>Detalii</th>
            </tr>";                             

            echo"
            <tr>
                <td>$DataInterval</td>
                <td>$Denumire</td>
                <td>$Moderatori</td>
                <td>$Detalii</td>
            </tr>";

        echo"
        </table>";
    }
echo"
</div>";
```

The problem is that if there are more than 1 row with the same id in the TabelAnunturi table, the header of the table is displayed for each row from table TabelAnunturi. If i move the WHILE statement between the rows of the table, the table header will be displayed regardless if there are no results for the query... I can't use while{ while{}} loop... i think that i must use `foreach` loop but how???

Comment: "where do I put a while loop in my code" is a sure offtopic question

Comment: Your `echo` statement will torture your server, don't `echo` so much html

Comment: @YourCommonSense i have edited the question... is ontopic now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put only the fetched data in the while loop.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($runtabelanunturi) > 0) {
 echo "<table class=\"anunturi\">
        <tr>
            <th class=\"dataanunturi\">Dată / Interval orar</th>
            <th class=\"denumire\">Denumire</th>
            <th class=\"moderatori\">Moderatori</th>
            <th>Detalii</th>
        </tr>";        
while($runrowstabelanunturi = mysql_fetch_assoc($runtabelanunturi))
{
    $DataInterval = $runrowstabelanunturi ['DataInterval'];
    $Denumire = $runrowstabelanunturi ['Denumire'];
    $Moderatori = $runrowstabelanunturi ['Moderatori'];
    $Detalii = $runrowstabelanunturi ['Detalii'];
    echo"<tr>
            <td>$DataInterval</td>
            <td>$Denumire</td>
            <td>$Moderatori</td>
            <td>$Detalii</td>
        </tr>";
}
 echo"
    </table>";
}
```

You were printing the whole table in every loop, this is the problem.try this.hope it will work.

Comment: but if i do that, as i said before, the header of the table will be displayed and i want it to be displayed only if there are results...

Comment: then first check for the fetched row count.if u want the header to be  printed for every record,then put it inside the loop.

Comment: read again the question... normally i don't want the table to be displayed if there are no results but if there are results, the header should be displayed only once and then the results. If i do it your way, the header will be displayed regardless if there are results or not...

Comment: i had this if condition... but i have this code (the above code) in another loop (a foreach loop) that makes the table header to be displayed in another place because there are results available in that query... it is hard to explain

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question:"How can I use the foreach loop?" : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @ionvoinescu Well your question is bad. Just mark an answer as answer.